# Selecting English letters inside a string with RTL letters

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the color of all English string in the given text:

```js
const english = /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/;

function getColored(text) {
  let result;
  result = text.replace(english, '<span class="colored">$1</span>');
  return result;
}

const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.innerHTML = getColored("این یک متن دو زبانه هست English is included البته با تفاوت هایی This is English too");
```

```css
.colored { color: #fc0303; }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

The problem is the regex does not select the English letters for some reason, How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your regular expression (english).
it should be
`/\w[\w\s]*\w/g`

In your regular express you are putting the `^` and the `$` which make it to match the whole string. which we dont want.
How  `/\w[\w\s]*\w/g` works is :

- the `\w` checks that it should start with a [a-zA-Z0-9]
- the `[\w\s]*` Checks that it can contain [a-zA-Z0-9] or a space also.
- the `\w` then checks that it should end with a [a-zA-Z0-9]
- the `\g`  at the end checks that it should not stop after the first occurance.

Comment: `\w` also matches underscores `_`, not just `[A-Za-z0-9]`. This will also not work for one-or two-character strings, like `I` or `am`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `^` and `$` characters from your regex, replace the `*` with a `+`, add `g` at the end and use a capture group (which will have index 1, thanks @pilchard!).

```
const english = /([A-Za-z0-9]+)/g;
```

The reasons for this are:

- `^` requires the match to start at the beginning of the string, but you want to match substrings at any position,
- `$` requires the match to end at the end of the string, but you want to match substrings at any position,
- `*` matches 0 or more characters, but you want to match at least one, which is what `+` does,
- The `g` flag stands for 'global', which means that you find all possible matches, rather than just the first one.

Comment: Now I get `$1` instead of English words with colors...

Comment: This will select each word individually and not the whole english sentence.

Comment: @AyushMaheshwari That is true, and I thought about that, but I did not want to change the content of the regex, only how it is applied. Adding the necessary `\s` should be easy enough.